# Как дописать к скрипту отправщик сообщений?

Tags: jquery, javascript, cms, html, php

Добрый вечер. Возникла острая необходимость сделать так чтобы сообщения введенные в форму отправлялись на емейл. Есть вот такая форма

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="discover_price" onsubmit="return checkForm('discover_price');">
    <div class="forma">
        <div class="bl02">
            <input type="hidden" name="is_submitted" value="Узнать цену" />
            <input type="hidden" name="main" value="" />
            <span class="bl03">Ваше имя *</span>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
            <span class="bl03">Ваш телефон для связи *</span>
            <input type="text" name="phone" />
            <div class="bl04">
                <div class="bl05">
                    Мы можем определить стоимость остекления Вашей квартиры по параметрам, которые Вы заполните в заявке и перезвоним Вам с готовым расчетом.
                </div>
                <span class="bl03 bl06">Название улицы</span>
                <span class="bl03 bl08">№ дома</span>
                <input type="text" class="bl07" name="street" />
                <input type="text" class="bl09" name="home" />
                <span class="bl03 bl10">Количество комнат в квартире</span>
                <input type="text" class="bl11" name="room" />
            </div>
            <div class="bt bt_01  bt_open4">Хочу узнать цену сразу</div>
            <div class="bt" onclick="$('#discover_price').submit();">Отправить</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

И есть Ява скрипт который проверяет что заполнены обязательные поля:

```
function checkForm(form_id) {
    name = document.forms[form_id]["name"].value;
    phone = document.forms[form_id]["phone"].value;
    bot_name = document.forms["write_review"]["main"].value;

    if (bot_name == '') {
        if (name == '' || phone == '') {
            alert('Заполните обязательные поля');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом возможно дописать отправку сообщений на емейл (самое простое это через php, как написать на php знаю, не знаю как отправить с этой формы теперь туда данные). Я использую CMS Simple там есть модуль CMSMailer (вроде такой). Либо подскажите как отправить данное сообщение через него. 
Очень необходимо решить данную задачу. Буду очень благодарен, в Ява скрипте не силен, только изучаю его.

Comment: Первая же ссылка в яндексе: [Почтовый модуль CMSMailer][1]

  [1]: http://www.cmsmadesimple.ru/features/moduli/cmsmailer

Comment: @klopp, мне не нужно показывать как подключить этот CMSMailer мне необходимо разобраться как используя Ява скрипт передать этому модулю информацию которую ввел пользователь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужно ничего передавать через javascript. И вообще, работая с CMS (любой) что-то расковыривать вручную.

В CMS Made Simple есть свои модули для создания и обработки форм, например, FormBuilder (у него в предустановленных образцах, кстати, есть и формы для отправки почты). Всё делается через него, и единственное, что нужно от вас - правильно настроить модуль CMSMailer. А вся "черновая" работа (проверка валидности полей и т.д.) будет делаться самой CMS.

Вот, на скорую руку сделал скриншоты, как в FormBuilder для CMS Made Simple редактировать форму из готового образца: [раз](http://ato.su/resizer/i/3/a/2400ef7e.png), [два](http://ato.su/resizer/i/6/2/793d6b3.png), [три](http://ato.su/resizer/i/e/0/a004e87f.png).